# How to convert multiple object to just one object with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

As you can see i have a multiple object like "123", "098", and "456", i want all of those object to be inside the object of multiple object.

Example:

```
var obj = 
{
  "123": {
    "name": "yourname1"
    "class": ["art","math"]
  },
  "098": {
    "name": "yourname2"
    "class": ["art"]
  },
  "456": {
    "name": "yourname3"
    "class": ["math"]
  }
}
```

output i expected:

```
{
    "number": "123",
    "name": "yourname1"
    "class": ["art","math"]
  },
  {
    "number": "098"
    "name": "yourname2"
    "class": ["art"]
  },
  {
    "number": "456"
    "name": "yourname3"
    "class": ["math"]
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?
I'm sorry im not show any javascript code cause until now I have no idea what to do

Comment: already answer your answer below, appreciate if you answer my comment, thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  123: {
    name: 'yourname1',
  },
  '098': {
    name: 'yourname2',
  },
  456: {
    name: 'yourname3',
  },
};
const obj2 = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({
  number: key,
  name: obj[key].name,
}));
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: this code work for me, thank you so much!.

Comment: Inefficient lookup for each name.

Answer (score 3):

You can map the Object.entries since there is 1:1 of the entries to the array item

```js
const obj = {
  "123": { "name": "yourname1", "class": ["art","math"] },
  "098": { "name": "yourname2", "class": ["class1","class2"] },
  "456": { "name": "yourname3" }
};

const arr = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([key, val]) => ({ "number": key, "name": val.name, "class": val.class || [] }));
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: May be the OP did not need the target to be an object - but rather an array? Because, the result generated is an array of objects - which is sensible (at least to me) - in contrast to the desired target/objective structure on OP's question.

Comment: It seemed quite obvious to me that op needs an object array which is what my code returns

Comment: but what if i want add one more key inside? like `{
  "123": { "name": "yourname1" , "class": ["art","math"]}
};` what ive to do?

Comment: i already edit my question above for detail sir, thanks if you want to help.

Comment: @mb-1208 I added class